# The union of two non-open disjoint sets in open

Tags: real-analysis

So I'm looking for an example of two sets, $A$ and $B$ in $\mathbb{R}$, such that $A$ and $B$ are non-open and disjoint and the union of $A$ and $B$ is open.

I was told this is possible but I'm having a hard time coming up with the two sets that work. Can someone help?

Comment: Hint: Half-open intervals.

Comment: $$A=\mathbb Q,\;B=\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$$

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to find two disjoint non-open sets $A,B$ whose union $U=A\cup B$ is open.

I guessed that non-open sets are easier to find than open sets, so, instead of picking two random non-open sets $A,B$ and hoping their union would be open, my plan was to pick an open set $U$ and hope I could partition it into two non-open sets $A$ and $B$.

Next, I had to decide what to use for my open set $U$. I figured, the bigger $U$ was, the more ways there would be to partition it into two sets, so I decided to pick the biggest possible open set $U$, namely $U=\mathbb R$.

Lastly, I had to pick some subset $A$ and hope that neither $A$ nor its complement was open.

First I tried $A=(0,1)$, but that didn't work because $(0,1)$ was open.

Next I tried $A=[0,1]$, but that didn't work because $U\setminus A=(-\infty,0)\cup(1,\infty)$ was open.

Next I tried $A=[0,1)$ . . . BINGO!

$A=[0,1)$ is not open, and $B=(-\infty,0)\cup[1,\infty)$ is not open, but $A\cup B=\mathbb R$ is open!

Answer (score 0):

How about $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R\setminus Q}$?

Comment: This feels like a comment, not an answer.